# Time independent Schrodinger equation and sign of $x$

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, parity

Say I have a wavefunction and a potential energy function that satisfy the time-independent schrodinger equation. I now change $x$ to $-x$ in both functions, does the time-independent schrodinger equation still hold for them? Do I still have a valid potential energy function and a valid wavefunction that satisfy the differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like
$$H(x)\psi(x)=E\psi(x),$$ then changing $x\rightarrow-x$ gives you $$H(-x)\psi(-x)=E\psi(-x),$$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian, $\psi(x)$ is the wavefunction and $E$ is the eigenenergy. Meaning that $\psi(-x)$ is an eigenstate of $H(-x)$.

It also works out in the time-dependent case by replacing $E\rightarrow i\hbar\partial/\partial t$.

If your Hamiltonian is $H(x)=-\hbar^2/2m\; \partial^2/\partial x^2+V(x)$, where $V$ is your potential function, changing $V(x)\rightarrow V(-x)$ is not enough sometimes, you need also to change the sign of the momentum $-i\hbar \partial/\partial x\rightarrow i\hbar \partial/\partial x$, but in the case above you  have the momentum squared so it does not matter (the sign of momentum could be important in interactions like the spin-orbit coupling).

Comment: So why does it work this way?

Comment: @AhmedSamir yes, there was a mistake in my initial response. As long as you change $x$ everywhere, then no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The time-independent Schrödinger equation in 1D reads:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2 m} \frac{d^{2} \psi(x)}{d x^{2}}+V(x) \psi(x)=E \psi(x)
\end{equation}

The solutions of this equation will be symmetric about x-axis:

\begin{equation}
\psi(x)=\psi(-x)
\end{equation}

Only if the potential function is also symmetric:

\begin{equation}
V(x)=V(-x)
\end{equation}

Note: the Laplacian is also symmetric:

\begin{equation}
 f(x) = f(-x) \Leftrightarrow \Delta f(x) = \Delta f(-x)
\end{equation}